# Pass a timestamp and calculate function time from c++ through to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I am passing data from c++ to C# via a dll and a callback. I would like to measure the time that this function takes.

I currently have in c++:

```
   std::chrono::milliseconds ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                    std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
```

And i am passing the `ms` variable through to C#. I then have:

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
Console.WriteLine("latency: " + Convert.ToString(millisecondsSinceEpoch - ms));
```

That prints:

```
latency: 63802044110874
```

1. Am I doing this correctly?
2. if so, how can I use that value to calculate the milliseconds between the two timestamps in a readable way?

Comment: `secondsSinceEpoch` -- are you sure that's in seconds, not millisecond? Be careful of timezones too: `DateTime.Now` is in your local timezone. Why not use [`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: Using :

` long secondsSinceEpoch =0;
            DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(secondsSinceEpoch);


gives me `latency:  -3457896901` What does this number mean? Thanks

Comment: DateTimeOffset isn't a number. DatetimeOffset from 0 is first of January 1970. At least if you just output the DateTimeOffset. At what property have you looked on the DateTimeOffset to get the number? And what do you consider as "readable" here? For me it would be the date string you get from DateTimeOffset.

Comment: in c++, I can run this twice: `std::chrono::milliseconds ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                    std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());` and negate the second result from the first. that gives me a millisecond value between the two timestamps. that is what i want here.

Comment: `(DateTimeOffset.Now - DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ms)).TotalMilliseconds` when ms is the value you get from your c++ code.

Comment: Thank you! that gives me 'DateTimeOffset does not contain a definition for TotalMilliseconds'

Comment: Then you got the parentheses wrong. DateTimeOffset-DateTimeOffset result in a TimeSpan that has TotalMilliseconds.

Comment: Got it. that prints: 

`latency: 1666447310877.31`

I am expecting a value of around 50 milliseconds. What does that number equate to, and how can i convert it to milliseconds elapsed between the two times?

Comment: That is now when ms is 0. I expected ms is the value you get marshalled from the c++ code.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing this correctly?

No. If the goal is to measure any kind of performance you need to use the high resolution performance counters, not the system clock. The system clock will typically have a resolution of 1-16ms, far to low for something like a method call.

In c# this is trivial get a accurate measurement:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Do method call

sw.Stop();
var elapsedTime = sw.Elapsed;
```

If you absolutely need to start your measuring from the c++ side you should be able to call QueryPerformanceCounter directly, see [Stopwatch Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs.html#fdc2549de79b2b71). At least on windows, linux should have something equivalent, but I have no idea what. I think there is also some standard c++ api for this, but I'm not a c++ guy.

Note that ideally you should be using something like benchmark.Net that does some statistics to ensure more accurate values.